# twisted get cipher name

Tags: python, twisted

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.defer import returnValue
from twisted.internet.ssl import CertificateOptions
from twisted.internet.ssl import AcceptableCiphers
from ssl import PROTOCOL_SSLv23
from ssl import DER_cert_to_PEM_cert
from OpenSSL.crypto import FILETYPE_PEM
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate
import time
import json

normalCyphers = AcceptableCiphers.fromOpenSSLCipherString(
    'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:'
    'DH+HIGH:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:'
    '!eNULL:!MD5'
)
normalCtxFac = CertificateOptions(acceptableCiphers=normalCyphers, method=PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

weakCiphers = AcceptableCiphers.fromOpenSSLCipherString('ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL')
weakCtxFac = CertificateOptions(acceptableCiphers=weakCiphers, method=PROTOCOL_SSLv23)


def asn1DateToTimestamp(asn1Date):
    expirationDate = time.strptime(asn1Date[:8], '%Y%m%d')
    return int(time.mktime(expirationDate))


class CertCheckProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, dfd, isWeakSsl):
        self.dfd = dfd
        self.isWeakSsl = isWeakSsl

    def connectionMade(self):
        reactor.callLater(0.01, self.getCert, 20)

    def getCert(self, depth):
        cert = self.transport.getPeerCertificate()
        transportHandle = self.transport.getHandle()
        if cert is None or transportHandle is None:
            if depth <= 0:
                self.transport.loseConnection()
                return
            reactor.callLater(0.01, self.getCert, depth - 1)
        else:
            cipherName = transportHandle.get_cipher_name()
            key = DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(cert)
            targetCert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, key)
            timestamp = asn1DateToTimestamp(targetCert.get_notAfter())
            expiresIn = timestamp - time.time()
            try:
                usedCipher = '  '.join(map(str, cipherName))
            except Exception:
                usedCipher = str(cipherName)

            self.dfd.callback({
                'name': 'certificate',
                'expiresIn': expiresIn,
                'sha1Digest': targetCert.digest('sha1'),
                'signatureAlgorithm': targetCert.get_signature_algorithm(),
                'issuer': targetCert.get_issuer().CN,
                'notAfter': timestamp,
                'notBefore': asn1DateToTimestamp(targetCert.get_notBefore()),
                'serialNumber': targetCert.get_serial_number(),
                'subject': targetCert.get_subject().CN,
                'sslVersion': targetCert.get_version(),
                'usedCipher': usedCipher,
                'weakCipher': self.isWeakSsl
            })

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if not self.dfd.called:
            self.dfd.errback(Exception('Connection lost'))


class CertCheckFactory(ClientFactory):

    def __init__(self, dfd, isWeakSsl):
        self.dfd = dfd
        self.isWeakSsl = isWeakSsl

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        self.dfd.errback(reason)

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return CertCheckProtocol(self.dfd, self.isWeakSsl)


@inlineCallbacks
def getCertificateInfo(ip, port=443):
    dfd = Deferred()
    factory = CertCheckFactory(dfd, isWeakSsl=False)
    reactor.connectSSL(ip, int(port), factory, contextFactory=normalCtxFac)
    try:
        res = yield dfd
    except Exception as ex:
        if hasattr(ex, 'reason') and 'HANDSHAKE_FAILURE' in ex.reason:
            dfd = Deferred()
            factory = CertCheckFactory(dfd, isWeakSsl=True)
            reactor.connectSSL(ip, int(port), factory, contextFactory=weakCtxFac)
            res = yield dfd
        else:
            raise
    returnValue(res)


@inlineCallbacks
def testit(ip):
    res = yield getCertificateInfo(ip)
    print json.dumps(res)
    reactor.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testit('x.x.x.x')
    reactor.run()
```

I'm not sure whether catching the handshake failure is correct for twisted. Still have to test that part with a server that has a weaker cipher.

This is the stacktrace to indicate that self._socket is none for the transport handle

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 825, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "C:\Users\sjuul\workspace\meuk\soCertQuestion.py", line 50, in getCert
    cipherName = transportHandle.get_cipher_name()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 838, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_cipher_name'
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named generic.utils` - please read the guidelines on http://sscce.org for formulating a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exposed fully publicly - feel free to file a bug on Twisted for this - but you can get to it via the pyOpenSSL API escape-hatch, with `self.transport.getHandle().get_cipher_name()`.

When I modify your example to remove spurious imports from the standard library `ssl` and pyOpenSSL `OpenSSL` modules, it works fine, and tells me google.com is using `ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.defer import returnValue
from twisted.internet.ssl import CertificateOptions
from twisted.internet.ssl import AcceptableCiphers

import time
import json

normalCyphers = AcceptableCiphers.fromOpenSSLCipherString(
    'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:'
    'DH+HIGH:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:'
    '!eNULL:!MD5'
)
normalCtxFac = CertificateOptions(acceptableCiphers=normalCyphers)

weakCiphers = AcceptableCiphers.fromOpenSSLCipherString('ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL')
weakCtxFac = CertificateOptions(acceptableCiphers=weakCiphers)


def asn1DateToTimestamp(asn1Date):
    expirationDate = time.strptime(asn1Date[:8], '%Y%m%d')
    return int(time.mktime(expirationDate))


class CertCheckProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, dfd, isWeakSsl):
        self.dfd = dfd
        self.isWeakSsl = isWeakSsl

    def connectionMade(self):
        reactor.callLater(0.01, self.getCert, 20)

    def getCert(self, depth):
        cert = self.transport.getPeerCertificate()
        transportHandle = self.transport.getHandle()
        if cert is None or transportHandle is None:
            if depth <= 0:
                self.transport.loseConnection()
                return
            reactor.callLater(0.01, self.getCert, depth - 1)
        else:
            cipherName = transportHandle.get_cipher_name()
            timestamp = asn1DateToTimestamp(cert.get_notAfter())
            expiresIn = timestamp - time.time()

            self.dfd.callback({
                'name': 'certificate',
                'expiresIn': expiresIn,
                'sha1Digest': cert.digest('sha1'),
                'signatureAlgorithm': cert.get_signature_algorithm(),
                'issuer': cert.get_issuer().CN,
                'notAfter': timestamp,
                'notBefore': asn1DateToTimestamp(cert.get_notBefore()),
                'serialNumber': cert.get_serial_number(),
                'subject': cert.get_subject().CN,
                'sslVersion': cert.get_version(),
                'usedCipher': cipherName,
                'weakCipher': self.isWeakSsl
            })

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if not self.dfd.called:
            self.dfd.errback(Exception('Connection lost'))


class CertCheckFactory(ClientFactory):

    def __init__(self, dfd, isWeakSsl):
        self.dfd = dfd
        self.isWeakSsl = isWeakSsl

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        self.dfd.errback(reason)

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return CertCheckProtocol(self.dfd, self.isWeakSsl)


@inlineCallbacks
def getCertificateInfo(ip, port=443):
    dfd = Deferred()
    factory = CertCheckFactory(dfd, isWeakSsl=False)
    reactor.connectSSL(ip, int(port), factory, contextFactory=normalCtxFac)
    try:
        res = yield dfd
    except Exception as ex:
        if hasattr(ex, 'reason') and 'HANDSHAKE_FAILURE' in ex.reason:
            dfd = Deferred()
            factory = CertCheckFactory(dfd, isWeakSsl=True)
            reactor.connectSSL(ip, int(port), factory,
                               contextFactory=weakCtxFac)
            res = yield dfd
        else:
            raise
    returnValue(res)


@inlineCallbacks
def testit(ip):
    res = yield getCertificateInfo(ip)
    print json.dumps(res)
    reactor.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testit('google.com')
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_cipher_name'` transportHandle._socket is None.  I'll add the rest of the code.

Comment: If you are getting that exception with my proposed code, then `transportHandle._socket` would be an attribute error, not `None`, because `transportHandle` is a `NoneType`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've updated the code now so that you can run it.

Comment: Thanks; I'll have a look.

Comment: The code has a couple of bugs but it seems to otherwise work.

Comment: You mean you don't have the NoneType exception? I'm wondering why it wouldn't work for me then. I'm running twisted 15.4.0 on 32 bit python 2.7.10 on windows 7

Comment: I see that `get_cipher_name` works. on a ubuntu host running twisted 14.0.2 on 64 bit python 2.7.9 and that indeed the rest of the code doesn't work yet.

Comment: `pip install -U pyopenssl` fixed it. Thank you for your time.